# Uploading a file to my Linux PHP web host through a URL

Tags: php, linux, apache, url, upload

First of all, I don't know if this is where I have to ask this question; so I'll count on the moderators to move it if need be.

I have a Linux PHP web hosting account on GoDaddy.

When I have to upload a file, I normally use FTP, either a client or the host's file manager.

However, if the file is one which I have to download from another website, I would prefer if I could "download" it directly to my hosting account; the reason being that I'm in Mauritius and our connection is among the slowest in the world. So I would prefer using the high (I'm just assuming it's higher) bandwidth of the host so that transfers go more quickly.

So, my question is: does anyone of you have a solution (PHP script, Java applet, or anything) that I could use to achieve that?

Thanks in advance,

Yusuf

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget I use it for downloading wordpress straight to a server

Answer (score 2):

First of this might be a security risk on your server.

Secondly, here's  little untested code:

```
<?php

echo 'get file...';

$data=file_get_contents('http://...target-url...');

if($data===false)die('Failed getting file.');

echo 'saving file...';

$succ=file_put_contents('...target-file...',$data);

echo $succ ? 'Success' : 'Failed saving file';

?>
```

---

Usable script (put into file "down.php" in your web root):

```
<?php
    echo 'get file...';
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['from'])die('Fail: Parameter "from" not set.');
    if(!isset($_REQUEST['to'])die('Fail: Parameter "to" not set.');
    $data=file_get_contents($_REQUEST['from']);
    if($data===false)die('Failed getting file.');
    echo 'saving file...';
    $succ=file_put_contents($_REQUEST['to'],$data);
    echo $succ ? 'Success' : 'Failed saving file';
?>
```

Usage (run it in from web browser):

```
http://yoursite.com/down.php?from=http://yourothersite.com/file-content.txt&to=/var/www/public_html/target.txt
```

**WARNING:** Make sure you remove script after use, it is a *grave* security issue.

Comment: In principle, yes - but it's going to fall over trying to load large files (and since the OP says it is to avoid bandwidth issues....) since the file is loaded into memory - a better solution would be $in=fopen($url,'r'); $out=fopen($file,'w'); while (!feof($in)) fputs($out, fgets($in, BUF_SIZE));

Comment: Good point symcbean. I've had this issue when running an uploaded SQL file and got it fixed with buffering. However, either case, you end up either increasing MAX MEMORY or MAX TIME. My option is bound to be faster, but more memory consuming, while yours slower and less memory consuming.

Comment: maybe i'll write a little script with this piece of code then.. though i'll have to do that when i have some free time for coding; i was looking for a "lazy" solution :S

Comment: Yusuf, I'll write a full one for you under the edited one. Please accept this answer if it helped you out.

Comment: I keep getting the failed saving error and its driving me crazy why am i getting this?

Answer (score 0):

[Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) I use it for downloading wordpress straight to a server:

```
 # Download the title page of example.com to a file
 # named "index.html". 
 wget http://www.example.com/
 # Download Wget's source code from the GNU ftp site. wget
 ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
```

The example are from the link above.

Comment: That's the only thing he didn't mention, ssh access ;). I think he'd find this rather problematic on shared hosting account.

Comment: True story. :)  Didnt really think about that

Comment: Ah!! I do have ssh access; though I don't think I have access to wget; that's the first thing I tried yesterday; they seem to have limited the commands available..

Comment: Check if they have `curl` or `ftp`.

Comment: They have FTP, but can you upload to an FTP using a URL directly?

I don't want to have to download the file and then re-upload it. If I have a link, I would like to upload it there directly from that link..

They have curl too.

Answer (score 0):

Christian trick make better with this code.

You can create a folder like d on your host and protect it with password! Then create a new index.php and put beloow code on it

```
<?php
 echo 'Get file...';
 $url = $_REQUEST['from'];
 $filename= preg_replace('/\\?.*/', '', basename($url));
 $to ='dl/'.$filename;
 $data=file_get_contents($_REQUEST['from']);
 if($data===false)die('Failed getting file.');
 echo "<br/>".'Saving file...';
 $succ=file_put_contents($to,$data);
 echo $succ ? "<br/>".'Success' : "<br/>".'Failed saving file';
?>
```

finally create a folder named **dl** to store downloaded files.

Usage (run it in from web browser):

```
http://yoursite.com/d/?from=http://yourothersite.com/file.txt
```